# How can I create perfect squares for specific CSS grid items?

Tags: html, css, layout, css-grid

I am trying to build a grid layout, where just the top-left, top-right, middle-left, and middle-right container make up a perfect square, while everything else should take up the space left. I saw solutions using a "padding-trick" and pseudo-elements to solve this, but only if all elements had to keep a specific aspect ratio.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;

  grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 0.5fr 1.5fr;
  grid-template-rows: 7rem 0.5fr 0.5fr 2fr;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.grid-container > * {
  background-color: #454545;
}

.grid-header {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 4;
}

.top-left {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
}

.top-right {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
}

.middle-left {
  grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 2;
}

.middle-right {
  grid-area: 3 / 2 / 4 / 3;
}

.bottom-left {
  grid-area: 4 / 1 / 5 / 3;
}

.bottom-right {
  grid-area: 2 / 3 / 5 / 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-header"></div>
  <div class="top-left"></div>
  <div class="top-right"></div>
  <div class="middle-left"></div>
  <div class="middle-right"></div>
  <div class="bottom-left"></div>
  <div class="bottom-right"></div>
</div>
```

How could I achieve this while still being able to make it responsive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the row auto height you can use the padding trick

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;

  grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 0.5fr 1.5fr;
  grid-template-rows: 7rem auto auto 2fr;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.grid-container > * {
  background-color: #454545;
}

.grid-header {
  grid-column:1/-1;
}

.top-left::before,
.middle-left::before{
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  padding-top:100%;
}


.bottom-left {
  grid-area: 4 / 1 / 5 / 3;
}

.bottom-right {
  grid-area: 2 / 3 / 5 / 4;
}

body {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-header"></div>
  <div class="top-left"></div>
  <div class="top-right"></div>
  <div class="middle-left"></div>
  <div class="middle-right"></div>
  <div class="bottom-left"></div>
  <div class="bottom-right"></div>
</div>
```

Like below to make sure there is no overflow:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  --d: calc((100vmin - 10rem)/2); /* take the smallest screen size and remove the gaps and header height */
  grid-template-columns: var(--d) var(--d) 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 7rem var(--d) var(--d) 1fr;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.grid-container > * {
  background-color: #454545;
}

.grid-header {
  grid-column:1/-1;
}


.bottom-left {
  grid-area: 4 / 1 / 5 / 3;
}

.bottom-right {
  grid-area: 2 / 3 / 5 / 4;
}

body {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-header"></div>
  <div class="top-left"></div>
  <div class="top-right"></div>
  <div class="middle-left"></div>
  <div class="middle-right"></div>
  <div class="bottom-left"></div>
  <div class="bottom-right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! If I want to make this responsive, I would have to "handcraft" the new grid for each specific breakpoint, right? So auto-flow in this setup will not get me anywhere, I guess..

Comment: Yes, but I mean that if I want the bottom-right container to be below all the other gird items on mobile, I would have to restructure the grid?

Comment: @Chris ah yes, you simply need to define the template using media query and adjust the variables based on your new template. It should be quite easy with the padding trick since you need to do nothing